# Copy constructor and getting data from methods

Tags: c++, object

So I'm trying to write a copy constructor for a class Orbit:

```
class Orbit
{
     private:
     vector<int> m_start;

     public:
     // ...
     const vector<int>& getStart() {return start; }
}
```

Like that:

```
Orbit::Orbit(const Orbit& toCopy)
{
     m_start = toCopy.getStart();
}
```

But all I'm getting is:

```
orbit.cpp:60:29: error: passing ‘const Orbit’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
   m_start = toCopy.getStart();
```

What do?

Answer (score 5):

You need to make the `getStart()` member function `const`. This is what the compiler tells you.

```
 const vector<int>& getStart() const {return start; }
```

Besides, you can live with the compiler-generated copy constructor in this case. It will do a member-wise copy, which is fine for `std::vector<int>`. This ships with the benefit that the compiler will also generate move constructor and move assignment operator for you (providing a custom copy constructor prevents this), which makes sense if you have a `std::vector` data member, as these are cheap to move-construct.

Answer (score 5):

you have to make your method `const`

```
const vector<int>& getStart() const {return start; }
```

Answer (score 4):

Non-const member functions can't be called on const object like `toCopy`. You have to mark `getStart()` as `const`.

```
const vector<int>& getStart() const { return start; }
//                            ^^^^^
```

BTW: Your copy constructor would default-initialize the data member `m_start`, then assign it in the body of copy constructor. It would be better to implement as

```
Orbit::Orbit(const Orbit& toCopy) : m_start(toCopy.m_start) {}
```

i.e. to initialize `m_start` directly; or apply the compiler-generated one, which does the same thing as above.

Answer (score 3):

Methods must be marked const in order to be called on const objects and references. Here's how you fix it:

```
const vector<int>& getStart() const 
{ 
    return start;
}
```

You can check the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#const-.2C_volatile-.2C_and_ref-qualified_member_functions) to learn more.

Note that you can use `auto` to simplify the signature:

```
auto& getStart() const 
{ 
    return start;
}
```